# Can't launch Barmalei Returns (Naujasis Barmalėjus Grįžta) game (Black screen, Error "DDrawPalette SetEntries: There is an undefined error condition")

Tags: compatibility, gaming

When I start a game (New Barmalei Returns / Naujasis Barmalėjus Grįžta), there is a crash to the desktop or a black screen with the error "DDrawPalette SetEntries: There is an undefined error condition". Compatibility mode doesn't help. Reboot too. Win10x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download dgVoodoo (for example, [here](https://github.com/dege-diosg/dgVoodoo2/releases/tag/v2.79.3))
2. Open the zip file and copy dgVodoo exe to your game directory
3. Copy all .dll files from MS folder to your game directory
4. Open the copied dgVoodoo exe file and configure it (don't close it)
5. Open the game

Related links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcCqfUR-Jqs
- https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-ddrawpalette/d15f7aaf-2e54-45f1-a0fd-10143b23d820